# DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.' Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, crystal-reports

I need my property to allow null, so I declare it as

```
Nullable<double> Nat_Salary
```

but when doing so, I get this error

> DataSet does not support System.Nullable<>.

This is my code to call the stored procedure and pass table to Crystal Report

```
if (Report_Number == "2")
{
   var Employee_Data = db.Database.SqlQuery<SR1_Result>("SR1").ToList();
   bs.DataSource = Employee_Data;
}

ReportDocument rpt = new ReportDocument();
rpt.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Report\\Arabic\\" + "R" + Report_Number + ".rpt");

rpt.SetDataSource(bs);
```

This is my class

```
public partial class SR1_Result
{
    public int EmployeeCode { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string JobName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date_Hiring { get; set; }
    public Nullable <double> Nat_Salary { get; set; }
    public string AdministrationName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SR1]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT         
        EmployeeCode,EmployeeName,
        JobName,
        Date_Hiring,
        Nat_Salary,
        AdministrationName,
        DepartmentName,
        BranchName
    FROM            
        Employee_List_Code_Name_Jop_DateHiring s
END
```

How can I fix this error without removing the nullable from the `Nat_Salary` ?

Comment: Run that by me again; what has any of this got to do with a DataSet?

Comment: @CaiusJard   i put returned  from stored procedure in DataSet .. and load DataSet  in Crystal report

Comment: None of the code on your post mentions a DataSet?

Comment: error is show here -- (rpt.SetDataSource(bs); )

Comment: My guess is that `bs` is a bindingsource (not that it's really relevant), and in the code you've shown the most recent thing you did with `bs` was set its datasource to a `List<T>`, which is not a DataSet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess, because the code you've shown doesn't actually mention or use a DataSet/DataTable at all, Crystal Reports is internally unpacking your `List<SR1_Result>` to a DataTable, and automagically creating the columns but is blindly passing the `Nullable<double> SR1_Result.Nat_Salary` to a `datatable.Columns.Add("Nat_Salary", typeof(Nat_Salary))` (or its reflective equivalent, and DataTable is objecting to a column being declared as Nullable

You'll have to fix up the shape of the object you pass in, and most sensibly it'll probably look like a DataTable that you create rather than leaving it to CR to do

Drop the `ToList` call and write a loop/some code that creates a datatable and populates it to pass to CR. The column can be declared as having a `typeof(double)` and also `AllowDbNull = true` then as you're populating, if the Nat_Salary is null, don't set a value for that column

Simplistically:

```
var dt = new DataTable();
...
dt.Column.Add("Nat_Salary", typeof(double)).AllowDbNull = true;
...

foreach(var x in db.Database.SqlQuery<SR1_Result>("SR1"))
  var ro = dt.Rows.NewRow();
  ...
  if(x.Nat_Salary.HasValue)
    ro["Nat_Salary"] = x.Value;
  ...
}
```

Or if there is a sensible conversion for Nat_Salary to a non nullable type you can `.Select` an anonymous type for CR to convert that uses a substitute value for Nat_Salary

```
var r = db.Database.SqlQuery<SR1_Result>("SR1").Select(x =>
  ...,
  Nat_Salary = x.Nat_Salary.GetValueOrDefault(0),
  ...
);
```

This will change the SR1_Result into an anonymous type that has a Nat_Salary that is no longer a `Nullable<double>` but just a normal `double` and CR won't explode when it is internally converting to datatable

---

In both these code samples the `...` are your other columns in `SR1_Result`. You're gonna have to list them out unless you want to get into doing the same reflective "look at the object, list its property names and types and turn it into a datatable but apply some custom logic if the property is nullable" process

---

Or, perhaps CR already ran into this broken behaviour and put out a version of CR that checks if the property is nullable, and makes a column that allows nulls of the type that Nullable wraps - check for updates/speak to CR (whoever owns them now)